# Matlab on macbook pro, retina

Tags: osx-mavericks

Hi I recently bought a macbook pro and just installed matlab 2013b.  I have a retina display, but the resolution of matlab itself when I run it, it does not look very nice, it's almost blurry and pixelated.  Does anyone else have a similar issue and is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 5):

Matlab 2013b uses it's own version of Java, rather than the OS X version (which is not installed by default). If you install the latest version of Java for the OS, and then replace Matlab's version, it should fix some of the problem: the text will be optimized for Retina, but the image still won't be.

The commands to replace Java are:

```
cd /Applications/MATLAB_R2013b.app/sys/java/jre/maci64
mv jre jre.orig}
ln -s /Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home jre
```

Alternatively, the last command might be:

```
ln -s /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
```

The commands are taken from Matlab Central's [thread 86910](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/86910#comment_180294).

Comment: Thanks I'll give it a try, but at the moment I've been using Matlab 2013a, and that corrects the resolution!

Comment: this works perfectly for me, thanks - MATLAB R2013b, MBP 13' late 2013