# Publishing a .m matlab file to pdf: display latex is blurred / poor quality

Tags: matlab, pdf, latex, markup

I'm using the command `publish('myFile.m', 'pdf')` within the Matlab gui. The resulting file is crisp and perfect except for any of the LaTex within it which is blurred almost to the point of not being readable. Where do you think the source of this issue is? Are there any workarounds?

*Context*: I'm using Matlab 2014a on a macbook pro retina. Problem persists for all other generation: issue is with the .png

*Note*: The whole GUI was completely blurred on install. I have since updated the version of java being used by Matlab using [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20532319/matlab-on-macbook-pro-retina):

```
cd /Applications/MATLAB_R2013b.app/sys/java/jre/maci64
mv jre jre.orig
ln -s /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk{jdk.version}.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
```

[Linked unanswered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24136800/how-to-avoid-pixelated-latex-equations-from-matlab-publish)

Comment: I hope someone comes in and proves me wrong, but unfortunately I think the answer is going to be that MATLAB's TeX and LaTeX implementations are limited, outdated, and broken. What you're likely seeing is that MATLAB is rendering the LaTeX, converting it to a picture (a png or jpg), and then inserting it back in at a low resolution. Try this [procedure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21948601/how-to-set-the-font-settings-in-pdf-publish-via-matlab-and-latex?rq=1).

Comment: @craigim, thank you for the link. It's proving horrible to select values. To make something sharp I need a scaling factor that restricts the LaTex to a very small box so that it cuts off the text. Do you think I can force Matlab to use a more up-to-date version of LaTeX?

Comment: In a nutshell, MATLAB's LaTeX engine appears to be hard-coded into a mex file, and is not accessible to modification or updates. There was a related discussion on [Undocumented MATLAB](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/matlab-latex-interface) regarding custom LaTeX fonts. If you have the time and the will, there does seem to be some information on ways to trick MATLAB into doing what you want it to do.

Comment: I would also add that the more people file bug reports on MATLAB's LaTeX support, the more likely it will get fixed.

Comment: Cheers @craigim. Yes, I think the issue lies within `snapTex` which is a 'pcode' file which is obfuscated and located at `/Applications/MATLAB_R2014a.app/toolbox/matlab/codetools/private`. I've submitted a bug [here](https://mathworksservicerequest.secure.force.com/apex/cp_case_detail?cc=uk&id=500i000000DdM1s). Should I raise it elsewhere?

Comment: it is possible to improve quality of rendered LaTeX equations, but you'll have to edit MATLAB functions.. See my answer here: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/49986-improve-quality-of-latex-equations-published-to-html-with-publish

Comment: @Amro, thanks for your input. Unfortunately, your answer is the same as [the workaround mentioned above](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21948601/how-to-set-the-font-settings-in-pdf-publish-via-matlab-and-latex?rq=1).

Comment: Based on the above comments, I think you are have misunderstanding how the equations are rendered. First MATLAB creates an invisible figure and plots the text of the equation rendered with the LaTeX interpreter. At this point, the font size can be set to anything and the text will appear as clear and large as you want with no jaggedness. Next MATLAB will capture the frame rasterized as an image (so at this point zooming will cause pixelation). What we suggested was to use a larger font size upfront (default 22pt later scaled by half), that way it appears slightly crisper (but still an image)..

Comment: However this whole approach is broken no matter what you set the font size, because the end result is still an *image*! Yet it's not the LaTeX engine's fault that the images are blurry! If you truly want equations in PDF to be vector graphics that can be infinitely zoomed (not some rasterized image), then you'll have to publish a LaTeX target, and then compile the file into PDF yourself (which is basically the answer you got from MathWorks support)...

Answer (score 1):

Answer from Matlab Support

> Hello James,
>
> I am writing in reference to your Technical Support Case #01107596
>   regarding 'LaTex rendering in very low quality when publishing'.
>
> I apologize for the inconvenience you experience. Unfortunately what
>   you observe is a bug in the way that "publish" renders LaTeX equations
>   when publishing to .pdf.  At the moment there is no direct work-around
>   for it.
>
> The best indirect work-around is to publish to LaTeX instead of .pdf
>   and then compile the resulting TeX file using a LaTeX compiler. I
>   appreciate that this work-flow is sub-optimal. The relevant
>   development team is already notified about it.
>
> I hope this e-mail clarifies the issue you experience. Once again I am
>   really sorry for this inconvenience. I will now close this service
>   request as having a bug report submitted but I will reopen it if you
>   require further clarifications. Do not hesitate to contact us again if
>   you have a new query regarding MATLAB's functionality.
>
> Please preserve the Reference ID below in further correspondence on
>   this query. This allows our systems to automatically associate your
>   reply to the appropriate Case.
>
> If you have a new technical support question, please submit a new
>   request here:
>   http://www.mathworks.com/support/servicerequests/create.html